# Credentials expired for online accounts

Tags: 20.04, online-accounts, google-calendar, gnome-calendar

I was trying to sync my google calendar with gnome-calendar, for that I added my accounts to ubuntu 20.04 but gnome-calendar didn't sync with them(don't know why) and after than when I restarted my laptop I saw that credentials for all of the accounts were expired.

[image]

Any clue why is this happening and why I am not able to sync the calendar?

Comment: How much time has passed since the time you added the account and the time you most recently synchronised your accounts? Google has a hard limit of 1 year for their TLS certificates (as does Mozilla and Apple). Non-corporate Microsoft accounts are usually good until 90+ days of inactivity. Not sure sure about Ubuntu's SSO certificate lifespan.

Comment: hardly 30 min...I added accounts, tried to sync calendars , searched a couple of mins on google, and then restarted

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i could fix a similar looking problem by executing

```
$ /usr/libexec/goa-daemon --replace
```

See this [comment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1340203#c69) on a Red Hat [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1340203) about `goa-daemon`.

Comment: This was useful for me for configuring pop os with i3 gaps and calendar sync

Answer (score 0):

I found this may works for you .

Try this:

Remove you Google account from Gnome Settings

Remove ~/.cache and ~/.config/goa-1.0

Sign in again for your Google account from Gnome settings, and give it some seconds to sync

Logout and login or reboot.

Original article https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/i8hhsj/gnome_calendar_is_not_syncing_with_google/g18hivm/?context=3